# Get element of list by variable in Django template

Tags: python, django

I have line of code in Django template:

```html
<h4>{{ totals.date.weekday }}</h4>
```

Totals is the Python list, how do i get item of this list by index stored in `date.weekday`?

This would look in Python like this:

```py
totals[date.weekday]
```

Creating another variable, which stores `date.weekday` doesn't work

**UPD:**

I found a solution:

Just added element of `totals` list to template context in render

For example:

```py
# ... 
return render(request, 'template.html', context={'date_total'=totals[date.weekday()]})
```

Comment: Here you are trying to access this: `totals[date[weekday]]`, right ?

Comment: @Plopp, i'm trying to access `totals[date.weekday]`

Comment: @Greenfield can you please post the sample list you want to iterate.

Comment: @lokesh
```python
totals = [
time(0, 0),
time(0, 0),
time(0, 0)
]
```
I wanna use `date.weekday` as index for `totals` list within Django template

Comment: date.weekday CANNOT be a variable name. In django, the dot is a shortcut, `date.weekday` means `date[weekday]`. Try to set and use `date_weekday` instead.

Comment: @Greenfield this looks like a time objects list. using this you can access hour, minute, second, microsecond, and tzinfo, not day/weekday.

Comment: @lokesh right, but i'm trying to get element of this list using `date.weekday` as it's index, because `date.weekday` returns integer

Answer (score 2):

You can access the array directly using

`{{ totals.0.date.weekday}}` where the 0 is the position that you want.

Also if you want to print all the elements in total you will need a for loop such as:

```
{% for d in totals %}
   {{ d }}
{% endfor %}
```

about sorting, you can use the pipe order_by but I recommend you to pass the list already ordered from the views

Comment: That's not what i want, i wanna get element of list in position, stored in `date.weekday` variable

Answer (score -1):

You have to run the "for loop" for this.

```
{% with counts = 0 %}
{% while counts < totals.count %}
      {% if counts == date.weekday %}
           <h4>total.counts</h4>
      {% endif %}
      {% counts += 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

I did not get your question completely but i think it might help.